# Retrieving source and destination table names in script

Tags: ssis, error-logging

I've created an SSIS package with a dataflow.

The oledb source uses a variable with a sql statement.

Following the oledb source, there is a derived column transformation that converts the data. 
If that breaks, it is redirected to a log table, if it doesnt break it goes to the oledb destination table.

Question: 
Is there a way I can determine what the source and destination tables are when the conversion breaks, for logging purposes?

Note: 
The source table is in the variable used by oledb source, and the destination is selected in the oledb destination task.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are already using data access mode "SQL command from variable". Let's say your variable is named "SourceQuery" and that you construct this in your package before the data flow task. Add 2 more package variables:

1. SourceTableName
2. DestinationTableName

Construct "SourceQuery" similar to the way you are doing now, but also store the table name in SourceTableName.

Change the destination task's data access mode from "Table or view" to "Table or view name variable" and select variable name "DestinationTableName". This could either have the correct table name as its initial value, or be set before the data flow task.

The variables SourceTableName and DestinationTableName will now contain the information you want for your logging.

Comment: Hi Chris - that is one good way to do it. Suppose we have 10 dataflow tasks, it would require 30 variables (10 queries and 20 tables). Is there another way to retrieve the information directly from a Script Component where the text for the logging is set up?

Comment: If you know at package design time the names of the source and destination tables in each of the ten data flow tasks, you could add another Derived Column component between each data flow's OLEDB source and the DC that is doing the conversion. This new DC can add columns SourceTableName and DestinationTableName set to the appropriate values. Unfortunately this will not work if your table names are determined at package execution time, e.g., in a Foreach loop container or from package configurations.

Comment: Is there a way to use the new derived columns (SourceTable, TargetTable) to the Script Component in the data source? It seems only the source columns from the oledb source can be chosen for input columns to the script component. thanks

Comment: @software_pulse [Here](http://imgur.com/rOSHN) is a picture of what I had in mind. "Add SourceTableName and DestinationTableName" is the DC I suggested adding, and "Combine names" is the DC whose failure you wish to track. If your script component is anywhere downstream of "Add SourceTableName and DestinationTableName" - e.g., attached to "Derived Column Error Output" between "Combine names" and "OLE DB Destination - Errors" - then the columns added by "Add SourceTableName and DestinationTableName" should be available.