# Dynamically Picking of Source table name & task name in audit/error handling in ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have designed a package in which I have 7 dataflows running in parallel.

I am doing Audit & error handling in which I want my source table name and that particular task name if any error occurs or failed.

How should I achieve this? Is it possible to store table name in one variable dynamically?

Comment: SSIS has an integrated logging mechanism in which you can tell where you want to log your operations, which operations you want to log (start, end, fail, warnings, etc.) and so on. Right click on the background of your DTS and click on Logging. As for the table name, I'm not sure you can dynamically get it, you will have to set it as a derived column or set it as variable on an error flow.

Comment: Hey Ezlo thanks for the reply. Getting source table name from  each data flow is the main task, whichever data flow is running have to get that flow's table name.

Comment: You can switch your source table access mode from "Table or view" to "Table or view name variable" and store your source table names in variables. You can then use the variable's values in your tasks. This will need you to create as many variables as sources you want to track. More here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743327/retrieving-source-and-destination-table-names-in-script

Comment: Where is this error handling occurring?